# Jquery Time Ago only in days

Tags: jquery, setting, days, timeago

I want jquery timeago only show me the timeago in days ! I meant when passed 30 days it will show me 31,32,32 days and not 1 month. Thanx for your pront answer.

Comment: Which plugin? You have to be more specific.

Comment: sorry i did meant pluging ! i meant the jquery timeago that you can find here http://timeago.yarp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to modify the plugin to get the behavior you described. Consider line 83 of **jquery.timeago.js**:

```
days < 30 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
```

As an example, if you change `30` to `40`, like so:

```
days < 40 && substitute($l.days, Math.round(days)) ||
```

the plugin will still show "x days ago" up till 39 days ago.

And if you want to disable units bigger than "days" altogether, you could just take out that portion within the assignment of `words`, like so:

```
var words = seconds < 45 && substitute($l.seconds, Math.round(seconds)) ||
            seconds < 90 && substitute($l.minute, 1) ||
            minutes < 45 && substitute($l.minutes, Math.round(minutes)) ||
            minutes < 90 && substitute($l.hour, 1) ||
            hours < 24 && substitute($l.hours, Math.round(hours)) ||
            hours < 42 && substitute($l.day, 1) ||
            substitute($l.days, Math.round(days));
```

Comment: hello andrewap ! thax for your answer ! It really help me.

Comment: @morrisonrox You're very welcome! Please consider accepting my answer by clicking on the giant green checkmark.